# Error in google apps script - Array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script

May I get some help on googlescript? This script is actually downloading responses from typeform into googlesheet. I have an issue in downloading.

error message:

> incorrect range width, was 11 but should be 12 At this line:
>
> doc.clearContents();
>
> doc.getRange("A1:L" + array.length).setValues(array);

Comment: Can you share the script which is producing the error?

Answer (score 1):

instead of hardcoding a part of your range definition try using a more reliable method like this :

```
doc.getRange(1,1,array.length, array[0].length).setValues(array);
```

if your array is right then it will work flawlessly .